# How to return file as stream using in Java using Spring framework on Windows and Linux

Tags: java, linux, spring, rest

Im developing a REST API in Java using the Spring framework. One of the endpoints is to return a file as a stream, I wrote this method:

```
@GetMapping(value="/v2/document/{guid}/file", produces = {"*/*"})
    @ResponseBody
    public ResponseEntity<StreamingResponseBody> getFile(@PathVariable("guid") String guid) throws Exception {
        String fileName = FindFile(guid);
        Path path = Paths.get(Paths.get(FileSystemRepository.reportsDir).toString(), Paths.get(fileName).toString());
        StreamingResponseBody responseBody = outputStream -> {
            Files.copy(path, outputStream);
        };
        HttpHeaders responseHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
        responseHeaders.setContentType(MediaType.valueOf(Files.probeContentType(path)));
        return new ResponseEntity(responseBody, responseHeaders, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

When I build my project and deploy it on a tomcat server on Windows, it works and it downloads the file as expected. However, when I host it on a linux machine, I get the following error when trying to download the file:
[image: Error when on linux]

The file I want to get exists in the path that I create in the method:
[image: File exists on linux]

Any ideas as to what is happening? My log isnt working correctly but if I get it working Ill update the ticket with the relevant information.

Comment: Mostly unrelated to the question, but I wonder what does this service return for guid=`%22..%2F..%2F..%2F..%2Fconf%2Fserver.xml%22` or `"../../../../conf/server.xml"`

Comment: @JockX I get a 404 not found

Comment: @JockX this one returns same 500 error I get origionally:
"../../../../conf/server.xml"